# Can you draw things that already exist? such as yourself or your pet?

Tags: quran, hadith

AssamuAlaikum

I understand drawing anything with a soul is prohibited, because of the hadith that you will be asked on the day of judgement to breath life in to it.

What does this mean for drawing a self portrait?
I am not inventing anything new, just painting what Allah swt has already breathed life into.

The same for my pet cat?
Or for example if you were choosing to draw a lion, you observe a real life lion and draw it, as it already exists, as opposed to drawing a lion from your imagination.

Or is this merely a loop hole?

Jazak Allah Khairun

Comment: Isn't all drawing just an imitation of something that already exists, as is your self portrait?